# Access objects of a class

Tags: visual-c++

A theoretical question. Please if it is unclear what I am asking please be so kind to comment it without blocking me, I will rephrase if necessary.

Suppose you have made a class and have made 100 instances of that class. (Simple class with just a name and an unique id number)

Now you want to find an object in that class but all you have is the idnumber. And you would need the name.

The objectname you used to instantiate the class for that specific instance, you can not know anymore.

How would the function to find the name based upon the idnumber that you have look like?

I hope someone has a code that shows me how this works.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::map<int, std::string>`, by any chance?

Comment: Maybe. What does this do? What I need is like the basic functionality of a database but than in a c++ program with classes. U give the id and u get the name returned.

Comment: `std::map<int, std::string> myMap; myMap[123] = "Hello"; std::string name = myMap[123]; /* name == "Hello" */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I expect that you have a very deeply flawed mental model of how memory allocation and de-allocation actually works. For example, do you understand heap vs stack difference? Do you understand what copy constructor is and what the "[rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))" is all about? Without understanding of those basic concepts you wouldn't be able to create any reasonably well working solution for your problem.

So when you say "have made 100 instances of that class", how exactly it happens that you still have them in the memory but can't enumerate?

If you really have the objects in the memory but no simple way to enumerate them, the obvious solution is to create an explicit data-structure that allows you enumerate objects ("registry"). The following code solves only very basic case in 2 ways: vector-based and map-based. Most probably you will need to create not just "global registry" but a specific registry for your factory method or something else. Still here is some code that might provide you some ideas:

**IdAndName.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::vector;
using std::find;

class IdAndName {
public:
    const int id;
    const string name;

    IdAndName(int id, string name);
    ~IdAndName();

private:
    static vector<IdAndName*> registryVec;
    static void addToVecRegistry(IdAndName* obj);
    static void removeFromVecRegistry(IdAndName* obj);

public: 
static IdAndName* findByIdInVec(int id);

private:
    static map<int, IdAndName*>registryMap;
    static void addToMapRegistry(IdAndName* obj);
    static void removeFromMapRegistry(IdAndName* obj);
public: 
    static IdAndName* findByIdInMap(int id);


};
```

**IdAndName.cpp**

```
#include "IdAndName.h"

IdAndName::IdAndName(int id, string name): id(id), name(name) {
    // 1) What is correct behavior if there is already such id for other object?
    //    For example what about values created by copy-constructor?
    // 2) What happens if the "id" field is not "const" and can be changed (especially in the map registry case)?
    addToVecRegistry(this);
    addToMapRegistry(this);
}

IdAndName::~IdAndName() {
    removeFromVecRegistry(this);
    removeFromMapRegistry(this);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////
vector<IdAndName*> IdAndName::registryVec;

void IdAndName::addToVecRegistry(IdAndName* obj) {
    registryVec.push_back(obj);
}   

void IdAndName::removeFromVecRegistry(IdAndName* obj){
    vector<IdAndName*>::iterator position = find(registryVec.begin(), registryVec.end(), obj);
    if (position != registryVec.end()) // end() means the element was not found
        registryVec.erase(position);
}

IdAndName* IdAndName::findByIdInVec(int id) {
    // or use std::find_if
    for (vector<IdAndName*>::iterator it = registryVec.begin(); it != registryVec.end(); ++it){
        if ((*it)->id == id)
            return *it;
    }
return NULL;  // What is correct behavior if there is no such object?
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////
map<int, IdAndName*> IdAndName::registryMap;

void IdAndName::addToMapRegistry(IdAndName* obj){
    registryMap[obj->id] = obj; // What is correct behavior if there is already such id for other object?
}   

void IdAndName::removeFromMapRegistry(IdAndName* obj){
    registryMap.erase(obj->id);
}


IdAndName* IdAndName::findByIdInMap(int id) {
    return registryMap[id]; // What is correct behavior if there is no such object?
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "IdAndName.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void initStack(){
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        IdAndName val = IdAndName(i, string("IdAndName #") + std::to_string(i));
    }
}

void testStack() {
    initStack();

    IdAndName* pId2Vec = IdAndName::findByIdInVec(2);
    // cout << "Found Vec " << pId2Vec->name <<endl; // bad idea
    assert(pId2Vec == NULL);

    IdAndName* pId2Map = IdAndName::findByIdInMap(2); 
    // cout << "Found Map " << pId2Map ->name <<endl; // bad idea
    assert(pId2Map == NULL);
}

void initHeap(){
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        IdAndName* val = new IdAndName(i, string("IdAndName #") + std::to_string(i));
    }
}

void testHeap() {
    initHeap();

    IdAndName* pId2Vec = IdAndName::findByIdInVec(2);
    cout << "Found Vec " << pId2Vec->name <<endl;


    IdAndName* pId2Map = IdAndName::findByIdInMap(2); 
    cout << "Found Map " << pId2Map->name <<endl;

    assert(pId2Map == pId2Vec);
}
```

**Self-assessment**

1. What is the difference between testStack and testHeap? Why one gets
   NULL and other works? Why lines commented as "bad idea" are actually bad idea?
2. What is the difference between vector-based and map-based solutions?
       Performance? Stability? Side-effects?
3. How copy-constructor might affect behavior of both implementations?
4. How non-const id might affect behavior of both implementations?

Comment: SergGr's. U are awesome! This particular code should be in every textbook! It contains all the information one needs to see an example to be able to use a class like a database. I have studied by heart ur code in the last 15 minutes. This will be a bookmark in my c++ coding. Thank you so much. U have explained hours of googling without finding a real answer how map and class are to be used together.

Comment: @Stephane, unfortunately this code is **not** "production-ready" by any reasonable standard and the important thing for you is to find out why it is not and how to tailor it for your particular scenario. Answering the self-assessment questions might be your **_first step_** in that direction.

Comment: Hello SerGr's. I have given it some thought. And I dare to answer ur first question about difference teststack and testheap. If I am correct. In teststack the instance will be overwritten every time it goes through the for loop as the name Val remains the same. In the testheap there is a new instance created in the heap for every i in the for loop. As every time  new gets executed a new memory location is reserved and a pointer to it. So this means that a class needs a new name or new memory location to be instanciated.

Comment: Is it possible though to so something like this. IdAndName (getline(cin,x)); so that u can choose the name under which the instance is made.

Comment: @Stephane No, name is create in exactly the same way in both `testStack` and `testHeap`. An interesting thing to try is to find out when destructors are called in `testStack` and in `testHeap` using debugger or by adding logging (I hope you know what a "destructor" is). P.S. I'm not sure I'll have time to answer your further questions.

Comment: Well now I am sure. The stack idea will call the destructor every iteration of the for loop as the memory doesn't survive. The heap idea makes them live till end of program as new memory locations are created upon every iteration.